# How to check user has put in correct number of arguments on command line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to check that the user has entered two arguments on the command line - the iface name and passive for a type of scan - I thought the script would just exit if the wrong arguments entered but it still prints out the error message no matter how many arguments entered - what am I missing ?

```py
import sys
import os

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
         print("not enough arguments")

         sys.exit(1)
    
    else:
        args = sys.argv

        if("-i" in args):
            i = args.index("-i")+1
            iface = args[i]
            print(iface)

        if("-p" in args):
            passive = args.index("-p")+1
            passive = args[passive]
            print(passive)
 
main()
```

Comment: So how many arguments are you entering? You should add `print(sys.argv)` as the first statement in `main()` just to check what you have.

Comment: To run teh scripty I do "python3 commandargs.py -i ens33 -p pass" - It gives me this back:

:'-i', 'ens33', '-p', 'pass'] ......

Comment: So you're well beyond two arguments - as far as `sys.argv` is concerned.

Comment: I see!  That has been helpful for me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.argv` also returns the name of the python file. Try running:

```
print(sys.argv)
```